# meaning of draw from

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of **draw from** in the following sentence

> The BLA, which **drew from** an earlier version, was reborn in 2000 when it claimed a few attacks on Pakistan targets.

[To  Read Full Article](https://www.thehindu.com/news/international/baloch-liberation-army-fighting-through-generations/article31990970.ece)

Comment: Since it's a paramilitary organization, it refers to some of the members also being members of an earlier organization, probably with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Draw is related to the word drag, and all its various uses relate to pulling. So you can draw a sword from its sheath or you can draw (tension) a bow. You can draw water from a well or cards from a deck. If you are drafted (drawn) then you are conscripted.

*Chambers* has: "to receive or take from a source or store". Here it is saying that the BLA had a supply of people and/or ideologies available from similar groups that had existed previously.